# Deleted a Block type LUN on Synology - is this recoverable?

Tags: synology, lun

Following some poor doco - a block type LUN on our company Synology was accidentally deleted with some business critical data on it. This LUN wasnt replicated anywhere or backed up. Is it possible to recover the data that was lost? Can this be done by SSHing into the NAS and working with the CLI?

I've submited a ticket to Synology and highlighted the issue, however being Australian we have to wait for their working hours to get any info back. Over the phone to them - I did hear that within the Storage Manager, under Volume, I can perform some action under the "Manage" option, however the Manage field is greyed out for me.

Part 2 of my question is: Is there a way I can find ou why this button is greyed out, so that i can investigate any options within that area for recovering my deleted LUN.

Any help would be severely appreciated.
Cheers,
Leon

Comment: +1 for eeaa ....... we know it's not help itself it's just path to follow, and since it was block type lun then no free/trial software available on market will be able to help you out. Just from curiosity what model of synology is it? cause i'm pretty sure that high-ends one are making mirroring without raid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Synology model was: RS3614xs+
We'ev got the machine off and have since found some of our data that's 6+ months old. Would still be nice to chase up this current data if possible.

Comment: did you had encryption on?

Answer (score 1):

No backups? Your option now is to shut the NAS down *now*, remove all of the disks, perform a block copy of all of them to another set of disks, and then send them to a place like Kroll Ontrack for recovery.

Warning, though: it *will* be expensive, and the data they recover may not be all-inclusive of what was on the deleted LUN.